# Is there a way to programmatically extract the sound portion of a Flash SWF file with .NET?

Tags: .net, flash, audio

Do any libraries exist with this functionality?  Any recommendations would be useful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no such thing as a "sound portion" in SWF files. SWF files may include embedded assets, such as images, fonts, video or audio.

I don't know about .NET solutions here. but I think the most simple way to do this is to use [swfmill](http://swfmill.org/) with swf2xml. you will find `DefineSound` nodes which contain the embedded sounds in base64 encoded form, as well as the format within the nodes attributes (can't find a reference for that right now). flash player does support some weird codecs, so you might be actually having to transcode the data in worst case.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the SWF as a FLV, like found on sites like Youtube, you can use FFMPEG. Unfortunately, there is few .NET wrappers, but they are out there.